# How many people are registered under the DACA?

Tags: immigration, daca

How many legally registered DACA recipients are on the book?

What is the total number of DACA recipients currently registered?

Comment: Could you explain the distinction between your two questions?

Comment: This is expected to change pretty much continuously, so in answers please explicitly reference the time the data refers to.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear as it is, it could benefit from a bit more explanation what is meant exactly in the two questions.

Comment: The suggestion seems to be that you can "illegally register". It appears to be a loaded question.

Answer (score 6):

the U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services said there were 689,800 active DACA recipients as of Sept. 4, 2017.[Factcheck org](https://www.factcheck.org/2018/01/daca-population-numbers/)

However, I still don't understand the distinction between the two questions.

Comment: On closer inspection the source is https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/Reports%20and%20Studies/Immigration%20Forms%20Data/All%20Form%20Types/DACA/daca_population_data.pdf which intentionally rounds.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt The document says "Totals do not add due to rounding" which implies that the sum is rounded separately and does not accumulate the rounding errors from all the numbers from individual origin countries. So the maximum inaccuracy due to rounding is below one per mille.

Comment: Yes, sounds like the sum has been rounded separately and does not accumulate rounding errors. So the actual sum seems to be between 689,751 and 689,850